# How to detect scrolling action in Android?

Tags: android

I have a horizontal scroll view, and I want to detect a scrolling action ,

1) is there a listener to detect when the user make scrolling ?

2) and can I know whether the scroll is left to right or right to left ?

EDIT :what is the required listener in HorizontalScrollView ? I don't find OnScrollListener !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go for Gestures. You will have callback methods like

1. onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent
   e2, float distanceX,float distanceY)
2. onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent
   e2, float velocityX,float velocityY)

Comment: was not able to use this...kindly provide more details

Comment: what kind of detail are you looking for? It answers the question i suppose.Implement OnGestureListener to have these callbacks.